# Grails App Engine Authentication

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, grails, authorization

How do I setup Account Registration, Login, etc in Grails when developing for the Google App Engine? Normally I would use the Acegi plugin but I've read that it doesn't work with Google App Engine.

For reference, I'm using the Grails app-engine and gorm-jpa plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google App Engine allows you to manage users through their [Google Accounts Java API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/users/overview.html). The page provides example codes which you can easily implement with Groovy.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at this patch: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILSPLUGINS-1233. I haven't used it yet but might be what you are after.

Comment: Cheers michael, I'll have to check it out

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it is essential to create custom authentication instead of using Google Account API to create any viable application run on GAE.

So, I created my own solution to tackle this problem which you may interested to have a look at URL:
http://grailsfuse.vobject.com/
(You will hit http 500 error for first request, please wait for 30 seconds and refresh)

The missing part is the self-registration page and remember me feature. Please contact us (hyperlink located below the page of URL above) if you are still interested.

Wish to heard from you soon!